# extraña respuesta en javascript archivo csv JS

Tags: javascript, csv

Estoy cargando un archivo csv desde el escritorio.
Pero el resultado me muestra

**\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000**

```js
const readFile = (event) => {
  //First File Upload
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      const dataset = fileReader.result;
      const result = dataset.split('\n').map(data => data.split(','));

      console.log(result);
      for (let fila = 0; fila < result.length; fila++) {
        if (fila != 0 && result[fila] != '') {
          const celda = result[fila].split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < celda.length; i++) {
            if (fila != 0 && celda[i] != '') {
              console.log(celda[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
document.getElementById('export_csv').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Archivo</span>
      </div>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="export_csv">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Archivo csv

https://filetransfer.io/data-package/sdPDYlyx

Comment: Tu archivo csv no es válido, ábrelo con el block de notas y te darás cuenta. Un csv es un archivo de texto plano y el tuyo no lo es.

Comment: @Yussef gracias x tu respuesta, el archivo nace desde una maquina llamada honeywell ck65. Si al abrirlo con block de notas no funciona.

Comment: Entonces, como te decia no es texto. y esto `fileReader.readAsText(file)` ya no tiene sentido